# $\omega_2$ is a not countable union of countable sets without AC

Tags: set-theory

This is an exercise from Jech 3.13

I would like to show that $\omega_2$ is not a countable union of countable sets without AC. I'm given the following hint: [image]

I'm not sure how to define the mapping. We know that there are isomorphisms, $f_n :S_n \to \alpha_n$, so if we define $F: \omega \times \alpha \to \omega_2$ by $F(n, \gamma) = f_n^{-1}(\gamma)$ if $\gamma \in \alpha_n$ and $F(n, \gamma) = 0$ otherwise, does this work? Also, if it works, does it avoid the axiom of choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, although I would take $f_n\colon\alpha_n\to S_n$. The reason this avoids choice is that $f_n$ is unique, so we don't need to choose it from anywhere. It is just the Mostowski collapse of $S_n$ (or its inverse in my suggestion).