# $\omega_2$ is not the countable union of countable sets

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm not sure I quite understand the form of the proof in this post '[$\omega_2$ is a not countable union of countable sets without AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044535/omega-2-is-a-not-countable-union-of-countable-sets-without-ac)' and similar ones. Is the idea to firstly show that there is an injection from the union into $\omega_1$, and then to show there is a surjection into $\omega_2$ to give a contradiction?

Comment: It is better to first understand these arguments in ZFC, *then* try to understand them in ZF.

Comment: It already makes sense to me in ZFC, since you have that the union is countable and therefore less than  $\omega_1$

Comment: That's *a different* argument. I meant *this* argument.

Comment: I don't what you mean by this argument? What part of this same argument can be done differently with choice?

Comment: I would suggest that you actually write down the details here, so that people can refer to specific lines rather than talking of *this* or *that* and causing misunderstandings.

Comment: The idea is to show that the existence of such a decomposition allows you to construct a surjection $\omega\times\omega_1\to \omega_2$ which is a contradiction (since you can show without choice that this would imply the existence of a surjection $\omega_1\to \omega_2$.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no surjection from $\omega_1$ onto $\omega_2$. So if a set can be mapped injectively into $\omega_1$, then it cannot be mapped surjectively onto $\omega_2$.

Comment: What is the purpose of the surjection, if we already know that the union is equal to $\omega_2$?

Comment: Your comment makes no sense to me. Can you clarify it?